# xmlstarlet how to insert text with quotes and apostrophes escaped as entities?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have a bash script and am trying to output some text into a node. That part works fine except that I would like for the text that is output to also escape quotes and apostrophes in addition to the basic escapes that are done for things like `<`, `>`, and `&`.

Example:

```
$ inxi -S|tail -3
    Kernel: 5.19.16-100.fc35.x86_64
    arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/1
    Distro: Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
 
$ xmlstarlet --version
compiled against libxml2 2.9.12, linked with 20914
compiled against libxslt 1.1.34, linked with 10135
 
$ printf '<foo>\n  <bar></bar>\n</foo>\n' | tee test.xml;
<foo>
  <bar></bar>
</foo>
 
$ xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "//bar" -v "I'd like <this> text to be \"escaped\"." test.xml ; cat test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar>I'd like &lt;this&gt; text to be "escaped".</bar>                                          
</foo>
 
$ xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "//bar" -v "I&apos;d like <this> text to be &quot;escaped&quot;." test.xml ; cat test.xml                          
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar>I&amp;apos;d like &lt;this&gt; text to be &amp;quot;escaped&amp;quot;.</bar>
</foo>
```

Desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar>I&apos;d like &lt;this&gt; text to be &quot;escaped&quot;.</bar>                                          
</foo>
```

Is there any way to achieve the escape style that I'm after either using `xmlstarlet` or other xml-aware tools (preferably ones available in Fedora central repos)? I was trying to avoid anything that wasn't specifically xml-aware but if `xmlstarlet` doesn't support this then is my best option to do the insertion like in the first example (`-v "I'd like <this> text to be \"escaped\"."`) then run some sort of post-process command like `perl` / `sed` / `awk` / `python` / etc? Perl would probably be my first pick of those listed but I am open to other tools if there is a better option.

Comment: Quotes and apostrophes don't need to be escaped for it to be valid XML. What's the context where you need this?

Comment: (if you have a consumer that doesn't work correctly without the extra escaping, that's arguably the code that needs to be fixed)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy don't necessarily disagree but as I can't change that and ultimately it *should* still be possible to do so bc the desired output *is* still valid xml (whether or not xmlstarlet supports doing it this way), my question remains the same. If all else fails, I was planning to do a targeted regex substitution with perl... Just feels hacky and was hoping someone might know of a better option

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14493/200657

Comment: @LMC looks close but I can't seem to figure out how to use that and make it apply within the context of a string being inserted into existing xml document. Doing e.g. `xmlstarlet unesc ed ...` and so on has no visible difference over examples in my main post. If you know how and could post a working snippet, would be happy to accept as answer. If I can either completely disable xmlstarlet's internal escaping and handle myself for the text in question or else tell it to escape the 2 additional characters, either approach would work.

Comment: `t=$(echo -e 'I\047d like <this> text to be "escaped".' | xmlstarlet esc); xmlstarlet ed -v "$t"`

Comment: @LMC ok, thanks for the example. Just tried that but seems to have the same result as the first example above for me (if it is working for you, do you have a different version / some config or exported vars?). Afterwards, I did `echo "$t"` and it seems to have `I'd like &lt;this&gt; text to be "escaped".` The changes in the actual file have the same thing

Comment: python could do what you want `python3 -c 'import sys;from html import escape; print(escape(sys.argv[1]))' $'I\'d like <this> text to be "escaped"\n'
I&#x27;d like &lt;this&gt; text to be &quot;escaped&quot;`

Comment: @LMC, except the goal is to put the escaped content _into an XML file_ in its literally emitted form. If the `&`s in the output get changed to `&amp;`s, that's no longer correct.

Comment: (...that if following HTML rather than XML escaping rules results in the OP's intended output, that does indeed imply a Python-based solution)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are correct, `xmlstarlet` will double encode `&quot;` to `&amp;quot;`

Comment: The `xmlEscapeEntities` function in [tag:libxml2]'s 
[`xmlsave.c`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/blob/master/xmlsave.c#L165) 
serialization module gives special treatment to `<>&` (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`)
but neither single nor double quote. 
There's no way to override this using [tag:xmlstarlet].

Comment: Thanks to all for the helpful comments. urcodebetterznow, appreciate you confirming that xmlstarlet is out of the running for this. CharlesDuffy yes exactly, you are quite correct that the double-escape is not desired. LMC thanks for the sample snippet. I had some other priorities come up today but will give the python route a try as soon as I get the chance.